# Angular2 Pipe can't remove letters in input

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to build a pipe in Angular2.  The "yearPipe" should only allow digits and limit the input length to 4.  I'm seeing some very odd behavior.

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="customer.year | year" (ngModelChange)="customer.year = $event">
```

The Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'year' })
export class YearPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val: string): string {
    if (val){
  let outputValue = val;
  outputValue = outputValue.replace(/\D/g, "");
  outputValue = outputValue.substring(0, outputValue.length < 4 ? outputValue.length : 4);
  console.log(outputValue);
  return outputValue
}
return "";
}
}
```

I have determined that my pipe cannot remove values, only add values.  So the attempt to limit the character count to 4 or remove non-digits fail. If I databind another variable to the same "customer.year" field, it displays the piped value.

example:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="customer.year | year" (ngModelChange)="customer.year = $event">
{{ customer.year }}
```

If I typed 2009asdf, {{ customer.year }}  would show 2008  while the input would show 2008asdf.  The example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/JAxA777p1dX8u2RpmvSA?p=preview  seems to be able to strip digits so I"m a bit confused. It's implemented the same as my pipe, so I suspect a version issue.  I'm currently using RC5 with the CLI.

Comment: So what you want? be clear about it.

Comment: Have you done anything to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried to implement a pipe, which apparently cannot remove values entered...only add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems we need to try some magic :)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, WrappedValue } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'year'})
export class YearPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val: string): any {
    if(!val) return '';
    return WrappedValue.wrap(val.replace(/\D/g, '')
        .substring(0, val.length < 4 ? val.length : 4))
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/TRLiYXQZOQLQWcaxr4Xz?p=preview)**

I think it should work in RC.5 as well